# Complex REGEXREPLACE with dots and special symbols in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-replace

I'm trying to extract values from the **text (column A)** into three columns with **array formula** in each column:

1. **Name (column C)**
   Text with numbers, dots and special symbols (like ',&,’) written together.
2. **First standalone number (column D)**
   It can have dots written together.
3. **Second standalone number (column E)**
   It can have dots written together.
4. **Sign (column F)**
   Just symbols + and -.

But now I can't get the **expected results (column C:F)**. I've texted my formulas in H:K range, but they are bad. Is it even possible to solve it with array formulas and regexreplace?

I will be grateful for advice!

**Example**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QKLM3rTFowKGF0WiUMsHI-UOvIJC85xxeQuIFhOILW0/edit?usp=sharing

**Expected Results** *(copy from Google Sheets)*

| **Text** | **Name** | **First Number** | **Second Number** | **Sign** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Word01.Text2 12.34 9.87** | Word01.Text2 | 12.34 | 9.87 |  |
| **+ 12.34 Text13 4** | Text13 | 12.34 | 4 | + |
| **Word 12 -** | Word | 12 |  | - |
| **10 1.5 Text. Word** | Text. Word | 10 | 1.5 |  |
| **Word. Word1 23.3 1** | Word. Word1 | 23.3 | 1 |  |
| **Word's1 7 +** | Word's1 | 7 |  | + |
| **14 Word&Text 2** | Word&Text | 14 | 2 |  |
| **Text’s.13 1.24 4.5** | Text’s.13 | 1.24 | 4.5 |  |
| **Word. 12 14 5** | Word. | 12 | 14 |  |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added possible regex solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QKLM3rTFowKGF0WiUMsHI-UOvIJC85xxeQuIFhOILW0/edit#gid=664394454):

first number:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(--REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A11,"(?:^|\s)([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*?)(?:\s|$)")))
```

second number:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(--REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A11,I3:I11&".*?\s([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*?)(?:\s|$)")))
```

Name:

`=INDEX(IFNA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A11,"(?:^|\s)"&I3:I11&"(?:\s|$)"," "),"(?:^|\s)"&J3:J11&"(?:\s|$)"," "),IF(LEN(K3:K11),"\"&K3:K11,),""),"(?:^|\s)[0-9]+(?:\s|$)",""))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Wow, you've considered every option!! The best! You give me motivation to study! Big thanks! :)